# MySQL: Allow for PHP code and SQL statements to be submitted by form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, suhosin

Here's my situation: I have a website built with CakePHP and MySQL. My website has a public forum where members can post code samples. Some of these code samples are going to include PHP and MySQL code.

I understand that this is probably a dangerous thing to allow, but for one: Only members whom I have specifically "approved" may post, and two: I believe CakePHP already uses parameterized queries... and while I'm sure there are still other risks involved, that is not what my question is concerned with.

**The problem:**

In my local testing environment, I can submit posts that include SQL statements and strings with php code like `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`; but, when running the exact same code on my production server, I can't.

Rather than being redirected to `/posts/index` (which is what normally happens after posting), I am redirected back to the same page I was on before (`/posts/edit/25`, for example). It seems that when I attempt to submit form data that includes "illegal" substrings, the submittal silently fails, and CakePHP just sends me back to where I was before. (No flash messages on CakePHP's behalf.)

**My diagnosis thus far:**

CakePHP's `/www/app/tmp/logs/error.log` shows no sign of an error after I attempt to post this data. I don't have access to any other server log files at the moment.

I tried removing some of the php code from my posts. I *was* able to submit strings like `<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>`, but if a function like `phpinfo()` was anywhere in the form data, the post would get "rejected". Stuffing my SQL examples with non-breaking-spaces also made it possible for me to submit form data that included SQL statements.

The MySQL user account that CakePHP uses is a little restricted. I forget exactly which actions it is allowed to perform, but I think they are just `select, insert, update, delete, create, drop`, and maybe a few others.

However, I also use phpMyAdmin locally to manage the production database, and when I access it via phpMyAdmin, I am using an admin account with maximum privileges. And when I manually change data through phpMyAdmin, strings like `phpinfo();` in my code examples *don't* get rejected!

Even though this seemed like a small glimmer of hope, I have tested my site with CakePHP setup to use the MySQL admin user with max privileges, but I still can't submit my unsafe strings via the user-facing form.

---

**My unsatisfying conclusion thus far:**

Since the exact same php code behaves differently depending on my environment, I suspect this has something do with my PHP version, MySQL version, or some security measure my sysadmin has put in place.

My sysadmin is rather hard to get in touch with though, so I'm trying to figure what might be causing the problem on my own.

### **My question:**

What might my problem be? Is there a PHP setting that prohibits "unsafe" strings, or some other commonly-known setting that I could request my sysadmin to change? Or perhaps might this be a MySQL setting? (Hard to tell given my phpMyAdmin's strange ability to do things that Cake can't.) Or how might I go about diagnosing this problem? (On my own; or, what kind of question I should ask my sysadmin?)

---

**More data that might be of use:**

So, this is my local testing environment according to phpMyAdmin:

```
Database server
---------------
Server: Local codeTech Server (Localhost via UNIX socket)
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server
----------
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.34
PHP extension: mysqli
```

And here is my production server's environment:

```
Database server
---------------
Server: Sam's Remote Server (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX via TCP/IP)
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.1.70-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: XXX@XXX.com
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server
----------
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.34
PHP extension: mysqli
```

I'd also be willing to post some portions of phpinfo for both servers, if that would help.

A few things I gleamed from phpinfo that may help diagnose the problem:

Local:

- PHP Version 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3
- Zend Engine v2.4.0

Production:

- PHP Version 5.3.26
- Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

  - with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd., and
  - with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies
  - with Suhosin v0.9.33, Copyright (c) 2007-2012, by SektionEins GmbH
- This server is protected with the Suhosin Extension 0.9.33

I suspect that this "Suhosin" extension might have something to do with it, though I'm not quite sure how...

Their page (http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/a_feature_list.html) suggests there may be a few "protections" in place:

- Transparent protection of open phpinfo() pages
- EXPERIMENTAL SQL
  database user protection
- Filtering Features

  - Configureable action on violation
  - just block violating variables
  - send HTTP response code
  - redirect the browser

In fact, this sounds highly suspect! I will probably have to have a talk with my sysadmin about this thing; unfortunately, the documentation on Suhosin is too sparse for me to know if it is actually the culprit, so I don't want to rule out everything else just yet.

Still, it might be important. These are the settings for Suhosin; they don't really make much sense to me, but maybe some PHP wizards can highlight some important keywords:

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
suhosin.apc_bug_workaround  Off Off
suhosin.cookie.checkraddr   0   0
suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot On  On
suhosin.cookie.cryptkey [ protected ]   [ protected ]
suhosin.cookie.cryptlist    no value    no value
suhosin.cookie.cryptraddr   0   0
suhosin.cookie.cryptua  On  On
suhosin.cookie.disallow_nul 1   1
suhosin.cookie.disallow_ws  1   1
suhosin.cookie.encrypt  Off Off
suhosin.cookie.max_array_depth  50  50
suhosin.cookie.max_array_index_length   64  64
suhosin.cookie.max_name_length  64  64
suhosin.cookie.max_totalname_length 256 256
suhosin.cookie.max_value_length 10000   10000
suhosin.cookie.max_vars 100 100
suhosin.cookie.plainlist    no value    no value
suhosin.coredump    Off Off
suhosin.disable.display_errors  Off Off
suhosin.executor.allow_symlink  Off Off
suhosin.executor.disable_emodifier  Off Off
suhosin.executor.disable_eval   Off Off
suhosin.executor.eval.blacklist no value    no value
suhosin.executor.eval.whitelist no value    no value
suhosin.executor.func.blacklist no value    no value
suhosin.executor.func.whitelist no value    no value
suhosin.executor.include.allow_writable_files   On  On
suhosin.executor.include.blacklist  no value    no value
suhosin.executor.include.max_traversal  0   0
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist  no value    no value
suhosin.executor.max_depth  0   0
suhosin.filter.action   no value    no value
suhosin.get.disallow_nul    1   1
suhosin.get.disallow_ws 0   0
suhosin.get.max_array_depth 50  50
suhosin.get.max_array_index_length  64  64
suhosin.get.max_name_length 64  64
suhosin.get.max_totalname_length    256 256
suhosin.get.max_value_length    512 512
suhosin.get.max_vars    100 100
suhosin.log.file    0   0
suhosin.log.file.name   no value    no value
suhosin.log.phpscript   0   0
suhosin.log.phpscript.is_safe   Off Off
suhosin.log.phpscript.name  no value    no value
suhosin.log.sapi    0   0
suhosin.log.script  0   0
suhosin.log.script.name no value    no value
suhosin.log.syslog  no value    no value
suhosin.log.syslog.facility no value    no value
suhosin.log.syslog.priority no value    no value
suhosin.log.use-x-forwarded-for Off Off
suhosin.mail.protect    0   0
suhosin.memory_limit    0   0
suhosin.mt_srand.ignore On  On
suhosin.multiheader Off Off
suhosin.perdir  0   0
suhosin.post.disallow_nul   1   1
suhosin.post.disallow_ws    0   0
suhosin.post.max_array_depth    50  50
suhosin.post.max_array_index_length 64  64
suhosin.post.max_name_length    64  64
suhosin.post.max_totalname_length   256 256
suhosin.post.max_value_length   1000000 1000000
suhosin.post.max_vars   1000    1000
suhosin.protectkey  On  On
suhosin.request.disallow_nul    1   1
suhosin.request.disallow_ws 0   0
suhosin.request.max_array_depth 50  50
suhosin.request.max_array_index_length  64  64
suhosin.request.max_totalname_length    256 256
suhosin.request.max_value_length    1000000 1000000
suhosin.request.max_varname_length  64  64
suhosin.request.max_vars    1000    1000
suhosin.server.encode   On  On
suhosin.server.strip    On  On
suhosin.session.checkraddr  0   0
suhosin.session.cryptdocroot    On  On
suhosin.session.cryptkey    [ protected ]   [ protected ]
suhosin.session.cryptraddr  0   0
suhosin.session.cryptua Off Off
suhosin.session.encrypt On  On
suhosin.session.max_id_length   128 128
suhosin.simulation  Off Off
suhosin.sql.bailout_on_error    Off Off
suhosin.sql.comment 0   0
suhosin.sql.multiselect 0   0
suhosin.sql.opencomment 0   0
suhosin.sql.union   0   0
suhosin.sql.user_postfix    no value    no value
suhosin.sql.user_prefix no value    no value
suhosin.srand.ignore    On  On
suhosin.stealth On  On
suhosin.upload.disallow_binary  0   0
suhosin.upload.disallow_elf 1   1
suhosin.upload.max_uploads  25  25
suhosin.upload.remove_binary    0   0
suhosin.upload.verification_script  no value    no value
```

---

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me troubleshoot this. And congrats on reading this far!

Answer (score 0):

About your PHP configuration differences between environments, you should compare the results of a phpinfo() execution in devel and production environments. Depending on the version, you can have magic_quotes activated (BAD IDEA!) or other configurations affecting your code, just compare one by one and you'll get the differences, which you should eliminate in almost all cases (except display_errors and a few more that need to be different in production and development).

About MySQL: you need to have two different users, which you will use depending on the query:

1. One for reading, with just SELECT permissions
2. The other for writing, with SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT (normally, CREATE and DROP are NOT necessary in a website and are a focus of possible security exploits)

Normally, you will use the "reading" user and you just change to "write" for the specific queries that need to write.

I don't think your problem is in PHP (but check the phpinfo) and positively is not in MySQL, my bet would be the Suhosin plugin and, maybe, a configuration in CakePHP that changes depending on your environment, but with the given information, I can tell no more.

I never heard about Suhosin and if I were you, my first step would be to deactivate it. Using [PDO's binding funcions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and [php filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) will be a secure option without extra plugins.